# Should I leave or strip embedded color profiles when using imagemagick to process images and embed on web?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Trying to convert a heic from an iPhone to a jpeg for web use without skewing the colors. When I strip all exif data, it skews the colors in the photo. If I leave them in, it appears to work although I'm not sure how compatible it is.

I also noticed when compressing using photoshop save for web, it strips everything out while maintaining the colors. I'm assuming it does some sort of color science after stripping exif data to try and maintain the colors without any exif. Not sure what the best practice is for modern browser and device support. I'm guessing it's impossible to achieve that with imagemagick.

Comment: Try converting to sRGB with -profile (assuming you already have some profile in the image). Then remove all color profiles with +profile "*".

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for this. If your intent is to not use a profile and need to strip all exif because of google insights or trying to save as much space as possible. Make sure and use the srgb.icc profile provided in the image Magick package when converting to srgb and image will be acceptable.

Cmd will look something like.

```
magick IMG_2253.HEIC -profile srgb.icc -strip x1.jpg
```